# What to do with questions about a problem that can be solved differently?

Tags: discussion

I asked [How to add a span before a tabs item?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163447/how-to-add-a-span-before-a-tabs-item) yesterday in order to put a small icon in front of a tab. It now turns out that I can achieve this by only using the default CSS classes and some CSS theming (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735394/add-image-to-left-of-text-via-css).

I'm now wondering what to do with my question, because there isn't actually given an answer for it, but my problem is solved nevertheless. On the one hand, I could answer it myself by giving the CSS code, but that would actually make the question off-topic. On the other hand, closing or deleting it doesn't seem appropriate, because the question can be useful in a different context.

What do you recommand me to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question can have more than one correct answer.  In your case, you have an alternate solution that achieves the end goal (getting the image in), but doesn't really answer the question (how to get a `<span>` before the link).  Someone may come along and answer the question and describe how to get the `<span>` in.

Comment: Okay, so do you suggest that I shouldn't post my CSS solution as an answer, but rather wait for a suitable answer (getting the `<span>` before the link) and accept that one? Maybe I can mention that my problem (adding the image) can be solved in a comment on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/163448/16550?

Comment: @Jeroen Feel free to add an answer if you feel it will help others. *Personally*, I don't think a CSS-only solution is appropriate for the question you asked (how to add a span).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'll add my solution as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is [an answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/163490/199) explaining how to do it the Drupal way, I would say you don't need to do anything with your question. That answer explains which theme function implement to obtain what asked.

The question doesn't explicitly ask for a CSS rule to change, but which function to use, and that part is Drupal-specific. Somebody who doesn't know Drupal could not answer that part, and that makes it Drupal-related.